# Перемещающаяся кнопка, как сделать OnClick?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Всем доброго времени суток!

Пусть есть любой `View` (для примера, кнопка), который должен постоянно двигаться и, в случае клика по нему, вызывать обработчик `onclick`. Я так полагаю, что если двигать кнопку, используя `translate-анимацию`, то кликнуть по ней можно будет только в том месте, откуда она начала движение, или в том, где прекратила движение.

Так не пойдет, нужно, чтоб в любом участке ее пути она была кликабельна там, где находится в конкретный момент. Можно заставить кнопку двигаться в цикле, изменяя ее `X-`, `Y-координаты`. Но тогда, я так полагаю, если зажать кнопку и подождать, пока она выйдет из под пальца в результате своей анимации, обработчик клика все равно сработает (или не сработает?). Нужно, чтоб он срабатывал только в случае, если палец был поднят от экрана в том же месте, где в это мгновение находится кнопка.

Как это реализовать, я не знаю, может, посоветуете пути решения?

В результате ответ, данный ниже, оказался правильным, вот реализация проверки, не ушла ли кнопка из-под пальца, если кому надо:

Я повесил на кнопку `onTouchListener`, и вот его код (`isOff` на входе `=false`):

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          firsttapX = motionEvent.getX();//берем Х и Y куда ткнули пальцем( по кнопке)
          firsttapY = motionEvent.getY();
          break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
           if (isOff==false) {
                dx = motionEvent.getX() - firsttapY;//получаем разницу между текущим
                dy = motionEvent.getY() - firsttapX;//положением кнопки и точкой куда мы 
                if (abs(dx) > 50 || abs(dy) > 50) {//нажали
                    isOf=true;
                    /*тут то, что я хотел реализовать по клику мимо кнопки или если она свалила из-под пальца, это же продублировано в onClick мимо кнопки*/
               }
           }
     break;
```

Если разница больше определенного числа (размер кнопки), то кнопка не под пальцем `isOff=true` перестает обрабатывать `ACTION_MOVE`.

Comment: Если вы хотите поделится собственным решением вашего вопроса, оформите его ответом, а не пишите решение прямо в вопросе. Так же вы сможете отметить его верным и получить за это заслуженную награду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html), то кликнуть по ней можно будет и в момент движения. Но это только для API 11+

Comment: Ну а как себя все поведет, если я зажму кнопку, и она, продолжая двигаться, выйдет из-под пальца. Обработчик сработает, когда я подыму палец?

Comment: @Sharlei не эксперементировал. Я  ObjectAnimator юзал для анимаций меню и т.п. То есть, кликал по начальному положению и конечному)

Comment: Да, по кнопке можно кликнуть в момент движения, все работает. Текст проверки, не ушла ли кнопка из под пальца напишу в вопросе, может, кому будет интересно.

Comment: можно использовать nineoldandroids библиотеку для анимаций на старых версиях андроид

Comment: @Andreich оно не будет кликабельно на старых версиях. Нажимать можно будет лишь на то место, где элемент был изначально.